# Best way to invoke factory method via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following class (with private .ctor and a public factory method)

```
public class TypeWithFactoryMethods
{
    private TypeWithFactoryMethods()
    {
    }

    public static TypeWithFactoryMethods Create()
    {
        return new TypeWithFactoryMethods();
    }
}
```

What is the best way to invoke the public factory method (Create) via reflection so I can get an instance of the type?

Comment: Is there an immediate benefit to using reflection to call a static method instead of reflection calling the constructor in this case?

Comment: I need it that way so I can get all factory methods and choose which one to invoke (passing arguments).

Comment: Bear in mind that using reflection for this kind of work is frequently a code smell.

Comment: Yes it is! It is not for production though what I try to achieve. Thanks a lot though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure what the goal is, but this would do it:

```
Type type = typeof(TypeWithFactoryMethods);
MethodInfo info = type.GetMethod("Create", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
object myObject = info.Invoke(null, null);
myObject.GetType(); //returns TypeWithFactoryMethods
```

**Update after comment**

If you want to find all methods that return your specified type you can use Linq to find them:

```
Type type = typeof(TypeWithFactoryMethods);
List<MethodInfo> methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(m => m.ReturnType == type).ToList();
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters(); //use parameters to decide how to invoke
    object myObject = method.Invoke(null, null);
    myObject.GetType(); //returns TypeWithFactoryMethods
}
```

Comment: I want to discover the "Create" method. The method names are not known to me at runtime.

Comment: @Nikos Baxevanis Updated my answer

Comment: So you want to discover a public static method that returns the type that contains it taking x-many arguments?

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Less code for same result:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TypeWithFactoryMethods));
            var method = Expression.Call(null,typeof(TypeWithFactoryMethods).GetMethod("Create"));
            Expression.Lambda<Action>(method).Compile()();
```

Comment: Yes, Expression Trees can really help in this example, but unfortunately you didn't re-implement the *correct* answer. As you can see in the update of Bas the name of the factory method is unknown at compile time. So please put in some little LINQ sugar to make it exactly matching.